# Does xpath query has Limit option like mysql

Tags: xpath, limit

I want to limit number of result I receive from xpath query.

For example:-

```
$info = $xml->xpath("//*[firstname='Sheila'] **LIMIT 0,100**");
```

You see that `LIMIT 0,100`.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to use `"//*[firstname='Sheila' and position() <= 100]`"

**Edit:**

Given the following XML:

```
<root> 
    <country.php desc="country.php" language="fr|pt|en|in" editable="Yes"> 
        <en/> 
        <in> 
            <cityList desc="cityList" language="in" editable="Yes" type="Array" index="No"> 
                <element0>Abu</element0>
                <element1>Agartala</element1>
                <element2>Agra</element2> 
                <element3>Ahmedabad</element3>
                <element4> Ahmednagar</element4> 
                <element5>Aizwal</element5>
                <element150>abcd</element150> 
            </cityList> 
        </in> 
    </country.php> 
</root>
```

You can use the following XPath to get the first three cities:

```
//cityList/*[position()<=3]
```

Results:

```
Node    element0    Abu
Node    element1    Agartala
Node    element2    Agra
```

If you want to limit this to nodes that start with `element`:

```
//cityList/*[substring(name(), 1, 7) = 'element' and position()<=3]
```

Note that this latter example works because you're selecting *all* the child nodes of cityList, so in this case `Position()` works to limit the results as expected.  If there was a mix of other node names under the cityList node, you'd get undesirable results.
For example, changing the XML as follows:

```
<root> 
    <country.php desc="country.php" language="fr|pt|en|in" editable="Yes"> 
        <en/> 
        <in> 
            <cityList desc="cityList" language="in" editable="Yes" type="Array" index="No"> 
                <element0>Abu</element0>
                <dog>Agartala</dog>
                <cat>Agra</cat> 
                <element3>Ahmedabad</element3>
                <element4> Ahmednagar</element4> 
                <element5>Aizwal</element5>
                <element150>abcd</element150> 
            </cityList> 
        </in> 
    </country.php> 
</root>
```

and using the above XPath expression, we now get

```
Node    element0    Abu
```

Note that we're losing the second and third results, because the `position()` function is evaluating at a higher order of precedence - the same as requesting "give me the first three nodes, now out of those give me all the nodes that start with 'element'".

Comment: Could you please clarify your question then?  What are you trying to extract from that XML?

Comment: Thanks Geoff for reply. but my xml format is quite different like <root>
<country.php desc="country.php" language="fr|pt|en|in" editable="Yes">
<en/>
<in>
<cityList desc="cityList" language="in" editable="Yes" type="Array" index="No">
<element0>Abu</element0><element1>Agartala%2A
</element1><element2>Agra</element2>
<element3>Ahmedabad</element3> goes on to like .... <element150>abcd</<element150>
</cityList>
</in>
</country.php>
</root> i had to select elements so my xpath(/root/country.php/fr/cityList[position() <= 10]) ... but it doesn't work please help !!

Comment: Geoff ... am doing pagination . i had to select the nodes[like element(n)] of in a bunch.

Comment: First: Is there a reason you have the number as part of the element name?  Better than `<element1/>` would be `<element num="1"/>`.  Second, do you have other entities contained in the cityList?  If not, it should be fairly simple - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi Geoff .. First: your suggested <element num="1"/> correct but i cant change this . i had worked for year this :( . Second: yes it can contain anything as node name and in any order. <br/> sdfasdf

Comment: Hi Geoff . First: i cant change structure to <element num="1"/> as I've worked on this for year :( . Second : yes entities can be anything and in any order .  if i do //cityList/*[position()<=3] am getting 3 results but output structure is totally different when compared to the //cityList .

Comment: <br/> 
I want this
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [desc] => cityList
                    [language] => fr|pt|en
                    [type] => Array
                    [index] => No
                    [editable] => Yes
                )
     [element0] => Abu
            [element1] => Agartala
            [element2] => Agra
 )
)

Comment: I Don't want :
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Abu
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Agartala
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Agra
 )
)

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean; you really want the original XML, but with the number of cities pruned to 100?

Comment: hi Geoff , could u reply please?

Comment: @ShivaKumarR - In that case it's not possible using XPath AFAIK; you should either using iterative coding to get the subset you need, or an XSL transformation; what language are you writing in?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue myself and had some issue with Geoffs answer as it, as he clearly describes, limits the number of elements returned before it performs the other parts of the query due to precedence.

My solution is to add the `position() < 10` as an additional conditional after my other conditions have been applied e.g.:

```
//ElementsIWant[./ChildElementToFilterOn='ValueToSearchFor'][position() <= 10]/.
```

Notice that I'm using two separate conditional blocks.
This will first filter out elements that live up to my condition and secondly only take 10 of those.