# Limiting list returned by xpath

Tags: xml, regex, xpath, webharvest

I am trying to use xpath in WebHarvest and I am able to receive a large list of data, however I only need the first 5 strings returned.

```
<var-def name="googleProducts">
    <html-to-xml>
        <http url="http://google.com/shopping?q=fila skele-toes&amp;hl=en"/>
    </html-to-xml>
</var-def>
<var-def name="googlePrices">
    <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@class='psliprice']/div[1]/text()">
        <var name="googleProducts"></var>
    </xpath>
</var-def>
```

I have tried using *[position()<6]
but i get the error **the value of attribute "expression" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character**

Comment: google it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107715/does-xpath-query-has-limit-option-like-mysql

Comment: I tried this but it is now returning a blank varriable

Comment: What is the full xpath statement that failed?

Comment: <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@class='psliprice']/div[1]/*[position() le 5]">

Answer (score 0):

This expression is valid, and should accomplish your goal:

```
<xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@class='psliprice' and position()<=5]/div[1]/text() ">
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/Eeuus/)

Comment: Did this work out for you?