# PHP xPath - How to limit the value in multiple queries?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have to select 3 of 4 values from each block in an XML document.
That works so far.

But now I have to limit the results.
Row[1] contains integers from 1 till 300 but I need the values only until 300.

```
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$this->nodes = $xpath->query("
        //row[position()>1]//cell[1]/data
        | //row[position()>1]//cell[2]/data
        | //row[position()>1]//cell[3]/data
        | //row[position()>1]//cell[data<300]
    ");
```

And the XML document Looks like this here:

```
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="Number">62</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">..</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Ethiopia PDR</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Ethiopia PDR</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="Number">63</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">EE</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Estonia</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">the Republic of Estonia</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

**EDIT:**

With your help it now works **but**:

```
$this->nodes = $xpath->query("
        //row[position()>1]/cell[data<300]/data
        | //row[position()>1]/cell[2]/data
        | //row[position()>1]/cell[3]/data
    ");
```

But now there are at the end some rows that the query seems to ignore:

```
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="Number">5600</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Antarctic Region</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Antarctic Region</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="Number">5706</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">European Union</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">European Union</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

Now the second "cell" is empty and the query ignores that only datasets lower then 300 shall be printed. Or better here is an unwanted result:

```
European Union - Antarctic Region
```

These and much more with an ID over 300 also shown in my result.
**I guessed I will only get row[1] + row[2] + row[3] ???**

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to get all `Cell` elements with a `Data` element containing a number lower than 300? Or do you want 300 results?

Comment: "Row" and "row" are not the same in XML/XPath. What's your problem anyway? An error message?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107715/does-xpath-query-has-limit-option-like-mysql

Comment: Only a "good practice", not a real problem: check your DTD, if all row have a cell, you can use `row/cell`, not need `row//cell`. About the query, if is a query for all cells, can use  `cell` not need `cell[1]|cell[2]|...`... all for reduce "noise" and complexity in your code.

Comment: Thank you, didn't see that double "/" before "cell". My fault.

Comment: PLease vote answers and check one as "accepted"... Or comment each answer about what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read my comments about complexity (it is ok your query?) try  `cell[data<300]/data`, that returns also data, not cell.

Summary:  perhaps an optimized query is something like

```
  //row[position()>1 and ./cell[1]/data<300]//data
```

But you say "3 of 4 values"  (and show that are the first 3)... Ok, now undertand... Check if the soution is,

```
  //row[position()>1 and ./cell[1]/data<300]/cell[position()<4]/data
```

Comment: Thank you that summary also works.

But I got now a new Problem. I will update my Topic.

Comment: @Tipo ok, check now my last solution

Comment: Nice!
Looks great Peter. Can I add one Negation to that Expression?
I found one Attribute "<CELL ss:StyleID="s64>" that I would like to exclude from my query.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately that Aggregation don't work. I can't get any result with that "and" in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Row[1]//Cell[1]/Data[.<=300]
```

Comment: That's it. I guess the "." solved it. Without the dot it ´doesn't work.